# При переходе (или перезагрузке) на страницу - сначала рендерится главная страница, а после - текущая

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, ssr

**ПРОБЛЕМА**: На сервере при заходе на любую страницу находящейся в директории, приложение рендерит изначально главную корневую страницу (index.vue) и только потом текущую страницу

**ПРИМЕР ПРОБЛЕМЫ**: Нахожусь на index.vue (http://domain) - перехожу на страницу profile/songs.vue (http://domain/profile/songs) - вижу как рендерится index.vue, а после нее рендерится profile/songs.vue

**ОСОБЕННОСТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ**: Эта проблема возникает только на сервере. При разработке на локалке такой проблемы нет

**ДЕТАЛИ ------------------------------------------------------------**

Деплой осуществляется через 2 команды - npm run build + npm run start

Роутинг создан дэфолтно через Nuxt с помощью файловой структуры директории (pages) + плагин i18n/nuxt

**ВОПРОС ------------------------------------------------------------**

Из-за чего эта проблема может возникать и как ее решить?

(Если нужна еще какая-то информация - напишите, что нужно предоставить)

Comment: Если есть возможность, создайте минимальный воспроизводимый пример(например с помощью https://codesandbox.io/), без кода очень трудно однозначно ответить на данный вопрос

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-sunset-xqlk3?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: Я воспроизвел ситуацию, но на sendbox проблема не видна